# Using yeast that's been proofed

Tags: yeast

I've just proofed a sachet of dried yeast and it seems to be fine (it's still foaming up the glass as I type).  Can I go ahead and use that very same batch of yeast to make bread (by including its liquid volume in the total ingredients) or it is now spent?  It seems like a waste not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, normally you proof yeast in part of the liquid from the recipe you are about to make.  If it is active, you continue to use the proofed mixture directly in the recipe.

Comment: Do you know how long can I keep it for, without using it?

Comment: Not very long.  You have activated it (since it was proofed).  You want to use it directly in the recipe for which you proofed it within a little while.  While I have never delayed longer than preparing ingredients required, I imagine a  half hour should be fine, maybe even a little longer.  You don't want the yeast in the proofing mixture to run out of food.

Comment: @Kate On the other hand, you can likely keep your dough for a while in the fridge, if you're trying to avoid baking now.

Comment: @Jefromi Good point, and that can help develop flavor as well as retard the rise.

Comment: @Jefromi When you say "a while", what's the maximum time?

Comment: @Kate That's a question all its own, so let's treat it as such: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/how-long-can-i-keep-bread-dough-in-the-refrigerator

Comment: @Kate You can keep it for probably a day or two without using it, but the longer it goes (anything over a few hours) the more it will contribute flavor but not leavening.