# Can i refrigerate bread doughs twice before baking?

Tags: baking, bread

Can i refrigerate dough twice? Such that after kneading i will refrigerate the dough overnight. Then after forming i will cold proof it. Will there be any deterrents?

Answer (score 2):

You can knead dough multiple times and let it rest in the refrigerator between. I do this to make a bread with a less tough crust and finer crumb.

Keep it covered and don't let it sit too long as described in [How long can I keep bread dough in the refrigerator?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/how-long-can-i-keep-bread-dough-in-the-refrigerator)

Comment: Thanks. So just to clarify, after kneading  i can put it in fridge overnight for first rise, correct? Then i take it out of fridge, shape it into balls and i can place it in fridge again overnight for 2nd proofing before baking next day, and this will be ok?